# KeyDown event not raising from a grid

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, keyboard-events

Here I have sample window with a grid. I need to capture event when key is pressed. But it is not raising when I click grid area and then press key. It will work only if Textbox is focused. I know it will work if I capture it from Window. But I have other application with few usercontrols and I need to capture it from distinct ones. I tried to set Focusable.false for Window and true for Grid but it not helps.
Any solutions?

```
<Window x:Class="Beta.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" Closed="Window_Closed_1" Focusable="False">

    <Grid KeyDown="Grid_KeyDown_1" Focusable="True">
    <TextBox x:Name="tbCount" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="35" Margin="310,49,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="83"/>

  </Grid>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Right this is weird. This is clearly a focus problem, still I can not understand why the grid do not take Focus, even when we click on it.

Though there is a workaround: create an handler for the loaded event of the grid:

```
<Grid x:Name="theGrid" KeyDown="Grid_KeyDown_1" Focusable="True" Loaded="TheGrid_OnLoaded">
```

And then force focus in your code behind:

```
    private void TheGrid_OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        theGrid.Focus();
    }
```

Your keydown event will work after that.
Hope it helps.

Comment: That's better but in my real application it fires keydown event from every usercontrol though I hooked it to only one. I have to investigate..

Comment: I have multiple windows, it wouldn't be right thing to make them all focused

Answer (score 7):

I had the same issue with a Universal Windows Platform (UWP) app. I attached the event to a grid in XAML but it would only work when the focus was on the TextBox. I found the answer (not just a workaround) on MSDN: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/56272bc6-6085-426a-8939-f48d71ab12ca/page-keydown-event-not-firing?forum=winappswithcsharp

In summary, according to that post, the event won't fire because when focus to the TextBox is lost, it's passed higher up so the Grid won't get it. `Window.Current.CoreWindow.KeyDown` should be used instead. I've added my event handlers to the page loaded event like this:

```
private void Page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Window.Current.CoreWindow.KeyDown += coreWindow_KeyDown;
    Window.Current.CoreWindow.KeyUp += CoreWindow_KeyUp;
}
```

This works as expected for me.

Comment: I think this answer told the best way to respond to the answer. It work on every situation.
NOTE: I suggest to add event handler on `OnNavigatedTo` and **DON'T FORGET** to remove the handler on `OnNavigatedFrom`

Answer (score 3):

I tried using the Focus Method too, to no avail, until I set the Focusable property to true ( It was default to False. )

Comment: Aha! That's what I was missing.  Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I've used `PreviewKeyDown`event and it worked for me.