# Key input not registering

Tags: c#, wpf

Im trying to make something happen when a key is pressed but my keyboard doesn't seem to be registering.
Im trying to make something happen with any key not specific ones.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace KeyDown
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public static IEnumerable<Key> KeysDown()
        {
            foreach (Key key in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Key)))
            {
                if (Keyboard.IsKeyDown(key))
                    yield return key;
            }
        }

        private void MainGrid_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if(KeysDown().Any())
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Key pressed");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Nothing happens, the `MainGrid` is focusable.

Tried this solution:
 [How to detect if any key is pressed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12076107/how-to-detect-if-any-key-is-pressed)
but still nothing happens.

Comment: you just defined an event handler. I don't see where you actually registered to the event.

Comment: Isn't `if(Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.Return))` the way to register any key?

Comment: This is WPF! Not asp.net!.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is also some discussion on this topic [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15241118/keydown-event-not-raising-from-a-grid). There is some issue with focus, try this:

XAML

```
<Grid x:Name="myGrid" Width="Auto" Height="Auto" KeyDown="MainGrid_KeyDown" Focusable="True" />
```

Code Behind

```
namespace KeyDown
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            myGrid.Focus(); // focus programmatically, better put it in OnLoaded event
        }

        private void MainGrid_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Key pressed");
        }
    }
}
```

My opinion is maybe `Grid` is hollow and is not intended for having focus, insert other controls which are better focusable and add KeyDown event to them. Also check there is some difference between [KeyDown](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.keyboard.keydown(v=vs.110).aspx) and [PreviewKeyDown](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.keyboard.previewkeydown(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a event handler in the constructor of the mainwindow. 
Something like this:

```
MainGrid.KeyDown += new RouteEventHandler(MainGrid_KeyDown);
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743596%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

remove the  if(KeysDown().Any()) in the event handler. And look what you get from the object sender and KeyEventArgs e.

Comment: The type or namespace name 'RouteEventHandler' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
System.Windows is being used.

Comment: Also isn't using the events list in the designer the same? as i made the event handler through there?

Comment: I think I'm remembering wrong - RouteEventHandler - it may be a just a eventhandler. Yeah, you can declare the events in the designer too.

Comment: I assume you wanted me to use a breakpoint, but the breakpoint never gets hit.

Comment: But if the if condition is gone, then would the messageBox show.

Comment: Put a another simple event like a click in there for testing

Comment: If condition gone, doesn't work. MouseDown doesn't work.. Added an Ellipse to use the handlers with, MouseDown works KeyDown still doesn't.